# MySQL Find Most Recent/Largest Record Per Group by order by

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

MySQL Find Most Recent/Largest Record Per Group by order by, and how can i minimize / shorten  this query and every time it returns the first row  value of the group, whereas i like to select the last row value of a group, and sort the values based on `ja.id` ? I know this is a bad query can anyone suggest or provide me solution to shorten this query . I have used all the necessary Column Indexes in all the tables. ***How to shorten the query without the use of union all .both the queries in union all are same expect in the where statement.***

```
SELECT
a.previous_status,
a.rejected_status,
a.rejection_reason_text,
a.rejection_reason,
a.rjaId,
a.refer_applied_status,
a.title,
a.playerId,
a.gameId,
a.gamePostDate,
a.game_referal_amount,
a.country,
a.country_name,
a.state,
a.location,
a.state_abb,
a.game_type,
a.appliedId,
a.appliedStatus,
a.admin_review,
a.is_req_referal_check,
a.memberId,
a.appliedEmail,
a.game_id,
a.referred_id,
a.memStateAbb,
a.memState,
a.memZipcode,
a.memCity,
a.memCountryNme,
a.memCountry,
a.appliedMemberName,
a.first_name,
a.primary_contact,
a.last_name,
a.addressbookImage,
a.userImage,
a.last_login,
a.user_experience_year,
a.user_experience_month,
a.current_designation,
a.current_player,
a.appliedDate,
a.addressbook_id,
a.joiningdate,
a.gameStatus,
a.gameReferalAmountType,
a.gameFreezeStatus,
a.gameFreezeMsg,
a.app_assign_back_to_rp_count,
a.applied_source,
a.max_id,
a.gamesApplied,
a.gamesAppliedId,
SUM(a.totalgameApplied) AS totalgameApplied,
a.application_assign_to_rp_status,
a.rpAppliedSource,
a.applied_on
                FROM
(
    (
        SELECT
            ja.previous_status,
            ja.rejected_status,
            ja.rejection_reason_text,
            ja.rejection_reason,
            rja.id AS rjaId,
            rja. STATUS AS refer_applied_status,
            jp.title,
            jp.user_user_id AS playerId,
            jp.id AS gameId,
            jp.posted_on AS gamePostDate,
            jp.game_referal_amount,
            jp.country,
            jp.country_name,
            jp.state,
            jp.location,
            jp.state_abb,
            jp.game_type,
            ja.id AS appliedId,
            IFNULL(ja. STATUS, '') AS appliedStatus,
            IFNULL(ja.admin_review, '') AS admin_review,
            ja.is_req_referal_check,
            usr.id AS memberId,
            rja.email AS appliedEmail,
            rja.game_id,
            rja.referred_id,
            mem.state_abb AS memStateAbb,
            mem.state AS memState,
            mem.zipcode AS memZipcode,
            mem.city AS memCity,
            mem.country_name AS memCountryNme,
            mem.country_code AS memCountry,
            usc. NAME AS appliedMemberName,
            usc.first_name,
            IFNULL(
                mem.primary_contact,
                usc.phone_number
            ) AS primary_contact,
            usc.last_name,
            usc.profileimage_path AS addressbookImage,
            usr.profile_image AS userImage,
            usr.last_login,
            mem.user_experience_year,
            mem.user_experience_month,
            mem.current_designation,
            mem.current_player,
            rja.create_date AS appliedDate,
            rja.addressbook_id,
            IFNULL(ja.joining_date, '') AS joiningdate,
            jp. STATUS AS gameStatus,
            jp.games_referal_amount_type AS gameReferalAmountType,
            jp.game_freeze_status AS gameFreezeStatus,
            jp.game_freeze_message AS gameFreezeMsg,
            ja.app_assign_back_to_rp_count,
            ja.applied_source,
            MAX(rja.id) AS max_id,
            GROUP_CONCAT(
                jp.title
                ORDER BY
                    rja.create_date DESC
            ) AS gamesApplied,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(jp.id)) AS gamesAppliedId,
            COUNT(DISTINCT(jp.id)) totalgameApplied,
            ja.application_assign_to_rp_status,
            1 AS rpAppliedSource,
            rja.create_date AS applied_on
        FROM
            (`refer_gameapplied` AS rja)
        JOIN `games_post` AS jp ON `jp`.`id` = `rja`.`game_id`
        JOIN `user_socialconnections` AS usc ON `rja`.`addressbook_id` = `usc`.`id`
        LEFT JOIN `user_user` AS usr ON `usr`.`email` = `rja`.`email`
        LEFT JOIN `user_member` AS mem ON `mem`.`user_id` = `usr`.`id`
        LEFT JOIN `game_applied` AS ja ON `ja`.`id` = `rja`.`applied_id`
        WHERE
            `rja`.`referby_id` = '2389'
        GROUP BY
            `rja`.`email`           
    )
    UNION ALL
        (
            SELECT
                ja.previous_status,
                ja.rejected_status,
                ja.rejection_reason_text,
                ja.rejection_reason,
                jr.id AS rjaId,
                jrtm. STATUS AS refer_applied_status,
                jp.title,
                jp.user_user_id AS playerId,
                jp.id AS gameId,
                jp.posted_on AS gamePostDate,
                jp.game_referal_amount,
                jp.country,
                jp.country_name,
                jp.state,
                jp.location,
                jp.state_abb,
                jp.game_type,
                ja.id AS appliedId,
                IFNULL(ja. STATUS, '') AS appliedStatus,
                IFNULL(ja.admin_review, '') AS admin_review,
                ja.is_req_referal_check,
                usr.id AS memberId,
                jrtm.referto_email AS refappliedEmail,
                jr.game_id,
                jrtm.id,
                mem.state_abb AS memStateAbb,
                mem.state AS memState,
                mem.zipcode AS memZipcode,
                mem.city AS memCity,
                mem.country_name AS memCountryNme,
                mem.country_code AS memCountry,
                usc. NAME AS appliedMemberName,
                usc.first_name,
                IFNULL(
                    mem.primary_contact,
                    usc.phone_number
                ) AS primary_contact,
                usc.last_name,
                usc.profileimage_path AS addressbookImage,
                usr.profile_image AS userImage,
                usr.last_login,
                mem.user_experience_year,
                mem.user_experience_month,
                mem.current_designation,
                mem.current_player,
                jrtm.refer_on AS appliedDate,
                jrtm.referto_addressbookid,
                IFNULL(ja.joining_date, '') AS joiningdate,
                jp. STATUS AS gameStatus,
                jp.games_referal_amount_type AS gameReferalAmountType,
                jp.game_freeze_status AS gameFreezeStatus,
                jp.game_freeze_message AS gameFreezeMsg,
                ja.app_assign_back_to_rp_count,
                ja.applied_source,
                MAX(jrtm.id) AS max_id,
                GROUP_CONCAT(
                    jp.title
                    ORDER BY
                        jr.refer_on DESC
                ) AS gamesApplied,
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(jp.id)) AS gamesAppliedId,
                COUNT(DISTINCT(jp.id)) totalgameApplied,
                ja.application_assign_to_rp_status,
                2 AS rpAppliedSource,
                jrtm.refer_on AS applied_on
            FROM
                (`game_refer` AS jr)
            JOIN `game_refer_to_member` AS jrtm ON `jrtm`.`rid` = `jr`.`id`
            JOIN `games_post` AS jp ON `jp`.`id` = `jr`.`game_id`
            JOIN `user_socialconnections` AS usc ON `jrtm`.`referto_addressbookid` = `usc`.`id`
            LEFT JOIN `user_user` AS usr ON `usr`.`email` = `jrtm`.`referto_email`
            LEFT JOIN `user_member` AS mem ON `mem`.`user_id` = `usr`.`id`
            LEFT JOIN `game_applied` AS ja ON `ja`.`referred_by` = `jrtm`.`id`
            WHERE
                `jrtm`.`status` = '1'
            AND `jr`.`referby_user_id` = '2389'
            AND `jrtm`.`refer_source` NOT IN ('4')
            GROUP BY
                `jrtm`.`referto_email`
        )
) a
                GROUP BY
a.appliedEmail
                ORDER BY
a.gamesAppliedId DESC
```

Comment: This is a big big query so we need sample data and expected result. We also have our day jobs.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ it seems to be a big query but i am just doing a union all... can u just help me out in shorten the query without the use of union all .both the queries in union all are just different in where statement

Comment: Shorthening the query is not simple task since we also need to make sure that the result is correct. We do this for free so we also need help to understand the data before we dig in.

Comment: Your queries are **NOT** the same, they draw different data from different tables.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ i know ... i will add the data in few minutes in the question

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a "groupwise-max" problem.  I added a tag that you should research.

At least get rid of the columns that are not relevant to the question.

Try tossing the tables other than jrtm and jr to see if the performance problem persists.  (I'm thinking that the `LEFT JOINs` may be red herrings.)

Try with one part of the `UNION`, then with the other.  This may identify which of the two is more of a burden.

Some indexes to add:

```
rja:   (referby_id, create_date)
jrtm:  (status, referto_email)
jrtm:  (rid, status, referto_email)
jr:    (referby_user_id, refer_on)
```

`DISTINCT` is *not* a function.  Don't use parents in `DISTINCT(jp.id)`.